# Vars_prompt register result to re use it as variable

Tags: ansible

With vars_prompt, I need to save a result as a variable to reuse it later as à condition. Î’musing

```
vars_prompt:
  - name : Toto or titi
    prompt : Toto or titi ?
    register: tototiti
    debug: msg= « test {{ tototiti }} »
```

But I get an error ERROR! ‘tototiti’ is undefined

Can you help

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You have a few problems, vars prompt is 1 part of your playbook and the printing of the variable should be on a "tasks" section, also on the prompt you don't need to register the value, you can access it by the name of the prompt:

```
---
  - hosts: localhost
    vars_prompt:

      - name : Totoortiti
        prompt : Toto or titi ?
    tasks:
      - name: print message
        debug:
          msg: " test {{ Totoortiti }}"
```

Comment: Thank you vert Much :)